# Problemas com o Rewrite PHP / Apache

Tags: php, apache, url-rewrite

Há 02 dias mudei de distro Linux e estou usando agora o Elementary OS. Instalei o Apache, Mysql e PHP manualmente, da mesma forma que instalei na distro anterior, porém estou com problemas com o Rewrite ( urls amigáveis ). Na distro anterior funcionou corretamente, mas nessa distro não está funcionando. Vejam abaixo o .htaccess, que funciona corretamente:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

No terminal dei o seguinte comando:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Reiniciei o Apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Em seguida, no arquivo:

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Incluí esse bloco:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Novamente reiniciei o Apache, mas mesmo assim o problema persiste, ou seja, quando clico no link do site: **fale-conosco/**, ele mostra que a página não foi encontrada. Vale lembrar que no servidor remoto e na distro anterior, funcionava corretamente e o arquivo fale-conosco.php existe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente dar um `chmod -R 777` dentro da sua pasta `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Olá Marcelo. Dei a permissão, mas o problema persiste.

Comment: Você já mecheu com o `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` porque a sua configuração parece estranha pra mim?

Comment: Eu mudo o `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` e o `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: O `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` não alterei. Qual tipo de alteração devo fazer nesse arquivo?

Comment: Desculpe, não consegui entender sobre a configuração diferente que você falou.

Comment: Me fale se conseguiu resolver o problema

Comment: Oi Marcelo. Nada... está dando o mesmo problema. Vou fazer o seguinte, vou reinstalar tudo, seguir as dicas que você passou e ver se o problema vai persistir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este é meu **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html  # << ANTIGO
    DocumentRoot /home/user/Desenvolvimento/web

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #REMOVI OS COMENTARIOS DESNECESSARIOS PARA A RESPOSTA
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
# .... alguns outros códigos também, mas o interesse é aqui

#<Directory /var/www/html/>     <<<DEFAULT  [padrão]
<Directory /home/user/Desenvolvimento/web/>  #TROQUE PARA o seu diretório desejado
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #AllowOverride None           <<< DEFAULT [pode ignorar]
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#alguns outros códigos......
```

Comment: Funcionou Marcelo. Retirei o código que havia incluído no `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` conforme seu modelo e incluí as linhas que você mencionou. Obrigado.